# Snap.svg inner shadow on animated arc

Tags: svg, shadow, snap.svg, svg-filters, svg-animate

I just starting working with svgs and Snap.svg library. Following a tutorial I created an arc progress indicator. What I want now is to add an inner shadow to the animated arc. I read the documentation but the `filter.shadow` command only gives the option for an outer shadow. I did some research on adding filters to regular svgs and I added one to the svg that I'm binding to my Snap object. It does give me the inner shadow, however it ruins the arc animation; only about half of the arc appears even though the inner shadow is present. I changed some of the filter settings trying to fix it but nothing works. I'm thinking that filter only works for static svgs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

**UPDATE**
Here is the code that I'm using.

```
<svg class="gauge" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 400 200" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#D1D2D1" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M199.7,12.7V18h0.4v-5.3H199.7z M382,200c0-50-20.3-95.4-53.1-128.4
    l8.4-8.4l-0.4-0.4l-8.4,8.4C295.6,38.4,250.1,18,200,18S104.5,38.3,71.5,71.2l-8.3-8.3l-0.4,0.4l8.3,8.3C38.3,104.5,18,149.9,18,200
    h44c0-38,15.4-72.4,40.3-97.4l7.5,7.5l0.4-0.4l-7.5-7.5c24.9-24.8,59.2-40.2,97.1-40.3v10.5h0.5V62c38.1,0.1,72.6,15.6,97.5,40.7
    c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4l-7.4,7.4l0.4,0.4l7.4-7.4c24.8,25,40.2,59.4,40.2,97.3H382z M102.3,102.6l0.3-0.3L102.3,102.6z"/>
</svg>



<script type="text/javascript">
var canvasSize = 400,
    centre = canvasSize/2,
    radius = canvasSize*0.8/2,
    s = Snap('.gauge'),
    path = "",
    startY = centre-radius,
    arc = s.path(path);

function fill(percent) {
    var endpoint = percent*180;
    Snap.animate(0, endpoint,   function (val) {
        arc.remove();
        var d = val,
          dr = d-180;
          radians = Math.PI*(dr)/180,
          endx = centre + radius*Math.cos(radians),
          endy = centre + radius * Math.sin(radians),
          largeArc = d>180 ? 1 : 0;
          path = "M"+startY+","+centre+" A"+radius+","+radius+" 0 "+largeArc+",1 "+endx+","+endy;
          arc = s.path(path);
          arc.attr({
            stroke: '#fff',
            fill: 'none',
            strokeWidth: 44,
          });
    }, 1500, mina.backout);


}

fill(50/100);
</script>
```

I added this code to the attribute to get an outer shadow.

```
arc.attr({
    filter : s.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(1, 1, 2, 'black', 0.5))
})
```

I was wondering if there's something similar for an inner shadow.

I also tried adding this to the the embedded svg and then adding the attribute to the animated arc thinking it might work like a regular, static svg. It does give me an inner shadow, however only part of the animated arc gets displayed; it gets displayed within a rectangle.

```
   <defs>
     <filter id="inner-shadow">
      <feGaussianBlur result="offset-blur" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset>
      <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="1" result="color"></feFlood>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="offset-blur"></feComposite>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA slope="0.5"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
     </filter>
   </defs>

        arc.attr({
          stroke: '#fff',
          fill: 'none',
          strokeWidth: 44,
          filter: 'url(#inner-shadow)',
        });
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: We need to see your code so that we can test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the filter area that its applied over so that it doesn't get cut off. The Snap code seemed to give an error for me, so I just tried it using the svg filter markup, as the problem seems to be SVG related, rather than Snap.

So the key bit to change would be..

```
<filter id="inner-shadow" y="-30" x="-30" height="400" width="500">
```

This gives an offset wider range. You can read more on that at [filter docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterEffectsRegion)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m7u8pcn/)

Comment: Thanx a lot, you're absolutely right. I tried adding similar attributes but I was still getting errors. I probably didn't have the correct ones. Once again, thanx.

Comment: I was looking into the error that you mentioned. And you're right, I was just testing on Firefox and I wasn't seeing any errors. However, I just tried on Chrome and I'm seeing the error: `Error: <filter> attribute width: Expected length, "undefined"` Any ideas on what could be causing it?? I followed the documentation

Comment: I followed the documentation that states what parameters to pass.
This is the code that I'm using:
'filter : s.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(0, 2, 3))'

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. I was using an old version of the Snap.svg source code. I just downloaded 0.4.1 and that one took away the errors.
Once again, thanx.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The original post you gave me works on Chrome and IE, but it didn't work on Firefox. I had to change the y and x to -1.

Comment: You must add " filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' " to the filter element if you want to size your filter region in pixels - otherwise Firefox will think that you want 30000% width.